# How to join IN SELECT with LIKE from many tables in?

Tags: select, sql-like

I'm trying to create a query that searches out all records that share a similar attribute like so:

```
select * from table_A 
where fullname like in (select firstname from employees where X)
```

Only thing is that this is just my pseudo code, I actually am sorting through many tables so the real query I have currently looks something like:

```
select * from devices 
where devicename like in (select X from X1 where T in (select T from T1 where Y in     (select Y from Y1 where Z in (select Z from Z1 where AreaName = '74';
```

I'm trying to use the join command but very confused on how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM devices d
 INNER JOIN X1 ON d.devicename like '%'||x1.X||'%'
 INNER JOIN T1 ON x1.T = T1.T
 INNER JOIN Y1 ON T1.Y = Y1.Y
 INNER JOIN Z1 ON Y1.Z = Z1.Z
 WHERE Z1.AreaName = '74'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go ....

```
SELECT D.* 
from Devices D
    inner join X1 X on D.devicename like X.X 
    inner join  T1 T on T.T = X.T
    inner join Y1 Y on Y.Y = T.Y
    inner join Z1 Z on Y.Z = Z1.Z AND Z.Areaname = '74';
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i give you the second query with Join syntax (well, i try to):

```
select * from  Z1 Z1_1 
    JOIN Y1 Y_1 ON Y_1.Z=Z1_1.Z 
    JOIN T1 ON T1.Y=Y_1.Y 
    JOIN X1 X1_2 ON X1_2.T=T1.T 
    JOIN devices  d ON d.devicename=X1_2.X
    where Z1_1.AreaName = '74';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM devices d
INNER JOIN X1 ON d.`like` = x1.X
INNER JOIN T1 ON x1.T = T1.T
INNER JOIN Y1 ON T1.Y = Y1.Y
INNER JOIN Z1 ON Y1.Z = Z1.Z
WHERE Z1.AreaName = '74'
```

Answer (score 0):

The "join" command runs a cross product of the two tables and then selects only the tuples/rows where the common column names have the same values.

So, for your query:

```
select * from table_A
where fullname like in (select firstname from employees where X)
```

would be:

```
select * from table_A
left join employees
on table_A.fullname = employees.firstname
where X
```